# Negated existential quantification in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given this input data:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix : <urn:schema#> .

<urn:data/EntryComponent/component1>
  a <urn:schema#EntryComponent> ;
  rdfs:label "geologic maps" .

<urn:data/MatchRecord/record1>
  a :MatchRecord ;
  :hasComponent <urn:data/EntryComponent/component1> ;
  :matchType <urn:data/exact> .

<urn:data/MatchRecord/record2>
  a :MatchRecord ;
  :hasComponent <urn:data/EntryComponent/component1> ;
  :matchType <urn:data/exact> .

<urn:data/MatchRecord/record3>
  a :MatchRecord ;
  :hasComponent <urn:data/EntryComponent/component1> ;
  :matchType <urn:data/close> .

<urn:data/MatchRecord/record4>
  a :MatchRecord ;
  :hasComponent <urn:data/EntryComponent/component1> ;
  :matchType <urn:data/close> .
```

I want results only where no `exact` match exists, only `close` matches, for a given component. Therefore, for this input data, I want *no* result to be returned.

However, when I try to do this with negation in SPARQL:

```
PREFIX : <urn:schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
  ?component a :EntryComponent .
  ?record a :MatchRecord .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?record :hasComponent ?component ;
            :matchType <urn:data/exact> .
  }
}
```

I get `<urn:data/MatchRecord/record3>` and `<urn:data/MatchRecord/record4>` as the result.

Comment: You wanted not exact, only close matches, and you got the two close matches. The query results correspond to your intention expressed in the query and in the description.

Comment: I do not agreee with your comment. The TO wants only components that are not used as exact match in any record. At least that's how I understand it. And this would also match the expected result being empty.

Comment: The cartesian in the query is the issue. This query does what you want: `SELECT * WHERE {
  ?component a :EntryComponent .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?record :hasComponent ?component ; :matchType <urn:data/exact> .
  }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser, thanks! This also helped me find some missing values in my dataset, because it also returns components that have no referring record at all.